# Making a four square gallary of photos with CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I am newish to programming. I understand there are tutorials on flexbox and great resources of understanding flex but none that are straightforward in the sense of understanding how to limit the number of photos you want in a single column with flexbox. Below I am creating a 4 square photo of a surf fin just for practice. But it seems I am getting 3 photos on a line instead of 2 and 2.

I want it to look like this: [image]

But instead it look like this:

[image: enter code here]

I know there is no code directly stating to do so but here is the code and html I have WITHOUT FLEX:

```
    <div class="galary">
      <img src="./row-1-col-1.png" style="max-width: 350px; height: auto;" />
      <img src="./row-1-col-2.png" style="max-width: 350px; height: auto;" />
      <img src="./row-2-col-1.png" style="max-width: 350px; height: auto;" />
      <img src="./row-2-col-2.png" style="max-width: 350px; height: auto;" />
    </div>
  </body>

.galary {
  margin-top: 5vh;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
}
```

Comment: Why not use CSS grid instead of flexbox?

Comment: Is grid the best way to acheive this goal?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nrkjcmgp/

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you to use grid box rather than flex box because grid box align contents into columns and rows easily and here is an example for the grid box

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 60%;
  height: 400px;
  background: darkcyan;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.i2 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.i3 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.i4 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img i1"><img src="x.jpg"></div>
  <div class="img i2"><img src="x.jpg"></div>
  <div class="img i3"><img src="x.jpg"></div>
  <div class="img i4"><img src="x.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can achieve the desired layout using flexbox

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery img {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an alternative approach using CSS Grid.

```css
:root {
  --imageWidth: 150px;
  --gridGap: 5px;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: var(--gridGap);
  justify-items: center;
  width: calc((2 * var(--imageWidth)) + (2 * var(--gridGap)));
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" />
</div>
```

For details on css grid, see [A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid)

Comment: Wow, this was really useful. I see the importance of the grid when it comes to problems like this one; in the sense of specifying how many rows and columns you want. I'm curious about how you came to the width line and how it changes based on added images (ex. I wanted 6 images on 2 lines). Additionally, flex seems better for keeping the images centered with responsiveness and resizing the browser? Is this true?

Comment: i have set grid's width equal to the width of an image multiplied by number of images on one line. I have also added the grid gap to the width as well.

Comment: Grid can also be used to center the images and handle responsiveness on small screens.

Comment: Thank you! I will look more into grid.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You can change the `/ 2`'s inside the CSS `calc()`s function to the number of images you want in a row. 
Note - `calc` is not fully supported in internet explorer. look [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc) for more info about that.

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  width: 710px;
  max-width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

img {
  margin-top: calc(10px / 2 * 2);
  width: calc(100% / 2 - 10px / 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/350/">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/350/">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/350/">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/350/">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on alot of the answers I looked into grid, It was as simple as this:

```
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery > div img {
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
}
```

and the html:

```
  <div class="gallery">
      <div>
        <img src="./row-1-col-1.png" />
        <img src="./row-1-col-2.png" />
      </div>
      <div>
          <img src="./row-2-col-1.png" />
          <img src="./row-2-col-2.png" />
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

For those beginning like me, flexbox is better used for a single column on a row but Grid is better when you want to use both columns and row (2 dimensional.)